# Make LinkedIn forget data collected from my e-mail address

Tags: email, linkedin, contacts

When I created my LinkedIn account, I made the big stupid mistake of letting the site wander through my mail. Is there any way how to make LinkedIn forget all this data about the people I ever mailed with?

(I'm not sure about the legal aspect of the problem. I suppose I have the right to get the data deleted. However, I prefer a standard way of doing things before using the law hammer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically as to your question, there is no way to make LinkedIn 'forget' the data. When you agree to sync your email connections, LinkedIn then sends one email to *every* address in your email contacts (even if you once sent an email asking for a refund on something - the system has no way of knowing who is and who is not important to you). After this first time, 2 more emails are sent reminding your email connections that you want them to join you on LinkedIn. So, each email connection receives a total of 3 reminders 'from you' asking to join you on LinkedIn.

You can rescind these emails by going to your Sent folder of your LinkedIn inbox and manually, one by one, deleting the requests. It is painful and tedious, but is currently the only way to stop these emails from going out.

There is no legal recourse, because you agreed to allow LinkedIn to take these actions when you agreed to sync your email with LinkedIn. It is there, in the fine print.

You certainly could, as suggested by another responder, delete this account altogether and begin again. If you do not have many valuable 1st connections, it may be your best bet. Be sure to use a completely different email address to set up the new account! And be sure to completely delete the old account, as it is a violation of LinkedIn user rules to have more than one account.

Good luck!